# Sinusoidal Function word problems: month and temperature $T(t) = 14.9 \sin {\pi \over 6}(t-3) +13$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions, word-problem

> The averge monthly maximum temperature of New York can be modelled by $T(t) = 14.9 \sin {\pi \over 6}(t-3) +13$ where $T$ is the temperature in Celsius and $t=0$ represents January. Predict when the temperature is $0$ $^{\circ}$C

I tried this:

$$0 = 14.9 \sin {\pi \over 6}(t-3) +13\\
-13 = 14.9 \sin {\pi \over 6}(t-3)\\
-27.9 = \sin {\pi \over 6}(t-3)$$
Let ${\pi \over 6}(t-3)= \theta$

$$\sin \theta = -27.9$$
$$*error$$

Then I was going to substitute the value of $\theta$ back into ${\pi \over 6}(t-3)= \theta$ to obtain the $t$ value.

How do I do this question?

Comment: You have to divide by $14.9$ instead of subtracting it.

Comment: I made a simple mistake. Thank you. @Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a simple arithmetic error. You should divide instead of subtract

$$ \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{6}(t-3)\right) = \frac{13}{14.9} = 0.872 $$

And then use inverse sine. You should know something is wrong since $-1 \le \sin\theta \le 1$